# System.out.println doesn't print anything inside eclipse console

Tags: eclipse

Good Evening, i faced a weird problem, i tried to print something in my servlet using `System.out.println();`
 but nothing appered in the console although all the check boxes in the preferences window of the console is checked! does any one faced this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you are looking at the right console by clicking on the little down arrow just next to the console icon in the console view. There you will have all the console of your workspace, be sure to pick the right one (normally the console of your webapp server).